How do I prevent losing the binoculars?
There is currently a bug in the game that causes you to drop the binoculars when you pick up a weapon or gadget from a crate. You can pick it back up again, but you'll drop it again if you equip a weapon or gadget.

There is a workaround to prevent you from dropping it after picking it back up again.
With the binocs still equipped, bring them up by holding the binoc key (RB on an Xbox controller), then while holding down the key, perform two or more melee strikes in rapid succession. Sometimes twice is enough, sometimes it works with three or four. Moving slightly forward at the same time might help… it's finicky. If done correctly, you will now have a weapon equipped, without dropping the binocs.
You can now even equip weapons and gadgets normally, but remember that every time you pick up something from a crate, you'll have to do this little dance again.
